# Outlook Interop Accessing Deleted Item Folder from Shared Calendar

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption, outlook-2016

Consider the following scenario: 
Sombody shared a calendar with me. I have full access to this calendar. When i delete an Item in the calendar the `Folder.BeforeItemMove` Event is fired. So far so good.
I want to Track deletion by check wether the MoveTo Entry id is `null` or the Entry id of the `Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems)` which works. 
Now back to the case where the item is in a shared folder:

- As per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/office/ff869575.aspx) the Property *olFolderDeletedItems* is a no go as parameter for GetSharedDefaultFolders() (Just to be sure i accessed the other folders which were allowed which worked)
- I tried to Iterate over the Stores collection. No calendar there
- I tried to Access the Store Property on the MoveTo folder -> `null`
- I tried to get the Store from the Session (to inspect the PR_IPM_WASTEBASKET_ENTRYID) -> Fails
- I *CAN* get the folder name Problem with this is , it might be renamed and/or localized and i do not want an array with all the deleted folder names floating around if i can't help it
- I tested all of this using either plain OOM or redemptions Folder interface

Any Ideas?

(Tested in Outlook 2016)

Comment: I'm confused: are you trying to access the Deleted Items folder in a Shared Mailbox?  Or trap when an item is deleted from a Shared Calendar?

Comment: The deleteion of an Item in a Shared Calendar (not a calendar from a shared Mailbox, these I can access with the stores method as i described).I am using the pattern described in the MSDN to wrap inspectors (No problems there I get the before delete event) But when a user deletes an appointment the only event you get are the folder events. If you wrap the items in the folder events, you get in 7 kinds of RCW hells.

Comment: Are you saying the AppointmentItem.BeforeDelete event is NOT firing for items in the shared calendar even though you have it trapped in an Inspector wrapper?

Comment: This would theoretically fire if it were wrapped, BUT, there is never a Inspector_New event for D'n'D or Items deleted via the context menu - Wrapping them on selection changes leads to all kind of funny business when there is also an inspector open event.

Comment: What's a "D'nD'?  BTW, you can trap the Ribbon control for context menus if you're working with selections.  But I hear you - trapping a delete for an item in all possible scenarios is a LOT of work.  This is where Redemption can be handy, as you can trap a single delete event for an entire Store.

Comment: D'n'D is Drag and Drop. I'll certainly try the Redemption way, but I am not too optimistic that I can get a hold of the Store for I cant get it via <code>Folder.Store</code> although <code>Folder.StoreId</code> holds the correct EntryID of the Folder

Comment: Stores wont cut it either, I can get the event that somthing happened but i cant cancel it , which is neccessary for my application

Comment: Yes, using Redemption for trapping global deletes won't help for a shared folder.  Are you say DnD doesn't fire NewInspector if you drag an email onto the Calendar module to create a new Appointment?

Comment: I ment DnD does not fire a new inspector when moving Appointments around, when creating Appointments everything works just fine. As a workaround I am accessing and releasing the inspector via Selection[x].GetInspector (which triggers the NewInspector)

Comment: If you need to trap moving an appointment from one Calendar to another in a folder view then you'll need to also trap Items.ItemRemove for the source folder.

Comment: No it's a movement within a folder

Comment: How do you mean? An item can't be moved to the same folder it is already in

Comment: I can drag an Appointment from Time A to another Time B in the same calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the Calendar as a Shared Calendar (e.g. Sent as EMail invitation to you via the OWA) deleted Items go to YOUR deleted items Folder. This you can get via 
`Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems)`

If the Calendar is in a second mailbox in your profile the deleted item go to the deleted items folder of THAT account which you can acces via

`Outlook.Store _Store = MoveTo.Store;`

`Outlook.Folder _Folder = MoveTo.GetDefaultFolder (OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems) as Outlook.Folder;`

You can differntiate these two scenarios by Checking if the `Folder.Store` is null (which it is in the case of an Shared non mailbox calendar)

Answer (score 0):

`RDOStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)` and `RDOSession.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)` both work in Redemption.

Comment: RDOSession.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems) wont work, as stated in the RDO Documentation : "The type of the folder. Accepts the same values as Namespace.GetDefaultFolder method in Outlook Object Model" and in the MSDN [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869575.aspx) They write that one mustn't use olFolderDeletedItems. Which is consistent with my error code of "Illegal argument"

Comment: On a sidenote: get GetSharedDefaultFolder(NameOrAddressOrObject, FolderType) needs An RDOAddressentry or RDORecipient or a name or an email Address

Comment: GetSharedDefaultFolder in **Redemption** has no such limitation. olFolderDeletedItems is just another default folder.

Comment: I tried your suggested method today again in an empty project. All I get is a COM Exception with the Info : "Could not find the Store DN". Which is expected since I only get an EntryID for the Store in the Folder object (either OOM or RDO), the Folder.Store property itself is null.

Comment: That sounds like an error returned when you try to open the shared mailbox, not when you open the Deleted Items folder. What is your code that opens the store?

Comment: You just gave me an Idea why this cannot be working ! In a situation where somebody shares only their calendar, I can access only this special Folder. Because it belongs to a Store I can "see" the StoreID, but not access Folder.Store. Which is also the reason I can't get access to the store, or to a Shared Default folder e.g. olDeletedItems, this works only if the user not only shared their calendar, but also their Mailbox.